# What does a definite integral from a function to function represent?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, soft-question

Everyone knows that integrating a function $f(x)$ from a to b can be represented by the area under $f(x)$ graph from a to b.

But If we are integrating lets say $f(y)$ from $h(x)$ to $g(x)$ what will the geometric interpretation of  this be ?
$$\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}f(y)\,dy$$
Example on this $$\int_{x^2}^{\cos x}\sqrt{1-y^2}\,dy$$
This isn't necessarily hard to integrate we can use trig. subs to get $$\frac12\left[y\sqrt{1-y^2} + \sin^{-1}y\right]^{\cos x}_{x^2} =\frac12\left[\cos x \sin x+x+\frac\pi2-x^2\sqrt{1-x^4}-\sin^{-1}(x^2)\right]$$

What will this new function represent ?

Comment: The answer of 5xum said it well.  Personally, I wonder if the OP (i.e. original poster) did not wish to have $~\displaystyle \int_{h(x)}^{g(x)} ~f(x)dx~$  represent $~\displaystyle \int_{h(x)}^{g(x)} ~f(y)dy.~$  That is, I wonder if the OP wants the same variable to be *involved* in both the limits of integration and the integrand.  The problem is that this makes the OP's intent *nonsensical* because in the presented integration, the variable used in the integrand is a dummy variable that is meaningless outside the integrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}f(x)dx$$ is *technically* not incorrect notation, but it is very dangerous use of notation, because it is very confusing to not the same symbol to denote the integrating variable *and* a variable *outside* of the interval. It is much better to write something like

$$\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}f(y)dy$$  which means the exact same thing as the original expression, but is much less prone to confusing the reader.

---

As for what the function "represents",  well, it represents, for each value $x$, the area under the function $f$ on the interval $[h(x), g(x)]$.

Comment: your right I'll edit it to be $f(y)$